# Check if given language is CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

Assume language $L$ as follow:-
$$
L = \{ a^n b^x c^m d^y | (n=m) \lor (x=y)\}
$$
Is it possible to design DPDA/NPDA for this? I know if the condition would have been "and" then it is not possible. But is it possible with "or"?

My approach:- 1. Push all $a$'s to the stack.

2. At $b$ define non deterministic behavior as follow:-

   2.1. Assume we are checking for $n=m$.So skip all the $b$'s.

   2.1.2.Whenever $c$ is encountered, pop $a$ for $c$.

   2.1.3. When $d$ is encountered check if stack is empty, if yes, then accept else reject.

   2.2. Assume we are checking $x=y$. So push all the $b$'s to the stack. Now when $c$'s are  encountered skip them.

   2.2.1. When $d$'s are encountered, count them with $b$'s which are on top of stack.

   2.2.2. When input is finished and stack is empty or contains only $A$, then accept else reject.

Comment: What do you think about your approach? Have you tried proving it correct? Do you have a question about a specific thing?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
L = \{ a^n b^x c^n d^y : n,x,y \geq 0 \} \cup \{ a^n b^x c^m d^x : n,m,x \geq 0 \}.
$$
Try showing that each of these is context-free individually.

Comment: Thanks.I was making it unnecessarily complex.It must be parsed by NPDA. DPDA will not be able to handle this.Am i correct?

Comment: This seems right, but requires proof.

Comment: I can use the properties.From your answer i can conclude that the two languages  are DCFL, and DCFL are not closed under union.Hence the result(L) is not DCFL. Next in the hierarchy is CFL. And as CFL are closed under union ,hence L is CFL but not DCFL.Will this suffice?

Comment: This is an awful argument. Try it on the languages $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$, for example (not to mention any DCFL language and itself).

Comment: I did't understand your point. Is my reasoning in the above question wrong?By DCFL are not closed under union i mean ,it may or may not be closed.

Comment: Exactly. So the argument "the class of DCFL languages isn't closed under union, so the union of these two particular DCFL languages isn't DCFL" isn't valid.

Comment: Yeah.I got that mistake.I don't know how should i prove that it is CFL but not DCFL. I was just trying to implement it in a deterministic manner.But it did'nt seem possible.